# Merge hard-reset and factory-reset?

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

Another two synonymously used tags: All 4 questions tagged [hard-reset](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-reset) deal with [factory-reset](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/factory-reset) (x67). In fact, except for one they are even tagged factory-reset additionally.

I'd suggest to merge those four questions into factory-reset, and optionally make hard-reset a synonym to factory-reset. Though Matthew may be correct that a "hard reset" originally might have referred to "hard reboot" (by removing the battery) -- everywhere I read about hard-resetting a device, the procedure decribed was in fact a factory reset.

Merging would be as easy as removing 3 tags from their respective questions, and just change a single one I guess ;)

Comment: Even if the usage is rare, I'm against merging. Matt's view on hard vs. factory reset (also mine): http://android.stackexchange.com/a/6423/15713

Comment: Edited the hard-reset tag wiki (and shamelessly copied parts of Matt's answer, ahem) :-) Maybe that helps.

Comment: Some discussion about it in the chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6100395#6100395

Comment: Better to just remove "hard-reset" from those few questions and let it die.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nooooooo. They are not the same.

Comment: In that case, some of the [tag:hard-reset] Qs are mis-tagged. Take a look at [Can we get rid of viruses by simply factory resetting the device? ](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26180/) -- clearly speaks about nothing else than factory-rest. Same for [How to hard/factory/whatever reset a 1.6 tablet whcih will not boot?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10931/). Makes half of them. The third is asking about "what's the difference between the two". So clearly to the ones who ask it seems to be the same ;)

Comment: Then re-tag them. You have the power.

Comment: OK, will do. That leaves only two of them there. Not sure about the threshold that makes a "useful tag"...